# Comparing Binomial Probability to Poisson Random Variable Probability

Tags: probability, number-comparison

A text file contains 6000 characters. When the file is sent by e-mail
from one machine to another, each character (independently of all other characters)
has probability 0.001 of being corrupted. Use a Poisson random variable to estimate
the probability that the file is transferred without error.

Compare this to the answer
obtained when you model the number of errors as a binomial random variable.

For the binomial probability I got 0.2471%(to 4 significant figs).

For the Poisson probability I got 0.2478%(to 4 significant figs).

However I'm not sure how I'm supposed to compare them, clearly I can see that the binomial probability is slightly lower, but I don't understand why this is the case?

Comment: I think that the point is not that one probability is higher than the other, but simply that there is not much difference between the two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=6000$, $p=\frac1{1000}$, and $X\sim\mathrm{pois}(n,p)$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(X=0) = e^{-\frac np} = e^{-6} \approx 0.002478752. 
$$
Now let $Y\sim\mathrm{Binom}(n,p)$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(Y=0) = (1-p)^n \approx 0.002471322.
$$
Since the difference is $-7.43006\times10^{-6}$, this is negligible.